# Joda api not return proper islamic date

Tags: java, jodatime

I am converting Gregorian dates to Islamic dates. I am setting its leap year pattern to Indian leap year but it is not working.

I make for loop and Gregorian date which takes current month and count is days and convert it to Islamic date. [What i want](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_JNN05eY-QSUFpdXJOVVByY0E/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my code

```
        for(int i=0;i<maxDay;i++)
        {
            eng.add(String.valueOf(i+1));
            DateTime dtISO=new DateTime(currentY,currentMonth+1,i+1,0,0);
            DateTimeZone asia= DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Riyadh");

            DateTime dtIslamic = dtISO.withChronology(
                    IslamicChronology.getInstance(
                              asia, 
                              IslamicChronology.LEAP_YEAR_INDIAN));
            String islamicDateArr="";
            split=dtIslamic.toString().split("T");
            split=split[0].split("-");
            if(i==0 || Integer.parseInt(split[2])==1)
            {
                isl.add(String.valueOf(split[2]+" "+islamicMonths[Integer.parseInt(split[1])-1]));
                continue;
            }
            isl.add(String.valueOf(split[2]));
        }
```

Comment: Have you also tried any other leap year pattern (Joda-Time offers 4)? If nothing works then I get the feeling there might be a bug because these leap year patterns should finally be different by one day.

Comment: Yes i tried it but nothing works...Is there any error in my code?? or there is any other api that works for me

Answer (score 1):

**Your code seems to be correct.**

Since you told me to have tried every of the four leap year patterns of Joda-Time without success I get the feeling there might be a bug or just a missing feature because among all supported leap year patterns there should be a pair of patterns which are different by one day (and you observe one day difference).

**Other people have already submitted bug issues. See here:**

[issue 163](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/163)

[issue 107](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/107)

As you can see it will be hard for you to convince the project leader to solve your problem for you. Maybe he is right when saying that Joda-Time has not a bug, but is just not complete.

Keep in mind that according to [R.H. van Gent](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/islam/islam_tabcal.htm) the calculated islamic calendar algorithm knows at least **8 instead of 4 variants** because there are 4 intercalary schemes and (for each scheme) two variations depending on the precise start of the islamic epoch (Thursday versus Friday epoch). So Joda-Time is just not supporting all variants.

**What are the alternatives to Joda-Time?**

a) [Java-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html) and its [backport Threeten-BP](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) (for Java-6+7) support the table-driven Umalqura-calendar of Saudi-Arabia (sighting-based). I am not sure if this solves your problem however (if not then you might supply a hand-written file containing the table data relevant for you - a lot of work). Note that both libraries don't support algorithm-based islamic calendars.

b) Some people have written their own home-grown workarounds. I have found this [hijri converter](http://www.coderanch.com/t/534271/java/java/Gregorian-Hijri-Dates-Converter-JAVA) via Google. No idea if this works for you.

c) IBM offers a [Hijri calendar](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/IslamicCalendar.html) in its ICU-project. It offers different leap year patterns than Joda-Time. Maybe it helps.

Side note: As you can see the current Java-support for Hijri calendars is not really satisfying. That is why I decided to set up a new implementation in my own library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/issues/91). It is scheduled for maybe 2-3 months later in autumn 2015.